# Why I cant create table directly using CREATE in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE 'my_custom_table'(
  id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
  name tinytext NOT NULL,
  text text NOT NULL,
  url VARCHAR(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY id (id)
);";

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $sql );
```

This is my code. It produce an error when I try to execute it. However, if I replace the `my_custom_table` string with a variable `$table_name = 'my_custom_table';` This works. Why??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper notation is:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_custom_table`
```

Single quotes define strings. Backticks escape table names.

It's possible you did this in your alternate version:

```
CREATE TABLE my_custom_table
```

The backticks are not required unless your table name contains a non-standard character (outside A-Z, 0-9 or _), or is a reserved word. It's safe to use them in all circumstances, though, if you prefer to be consistent.

Comment: thx bro I dont know about this before, is there any reference so i can know more about it?

Comment: [The documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/) is a good place to start. Each command is described in detail, with references to the allowed format for each argument. Example: [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html) references `tbl_name` which is described in more detail in the [identifiers specification](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html).